# Having trouble importing the CSS file for vue-shepherd

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to get `vue-shepherd` running and one of the steps is this:

You will need to import the styles first:

```
@import '~shepherd.js/dist/css/shepherd.css';
```

but when I do this:

```
<style lang='css'>
  @import '~shepherd.js/dist/css/shepherd.css';
</style>
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Failed to find '~shepherd.js/dist/css/shepherd.css'
```

I've added both these plugins to my package.json

```
 "shepherd.js": "^8.1.0",
 "vue-shepherd": "^0.2.1",
```

How am I supposed to import the vue-shepherd CSS file into Vue?

EDIT:

This is the complete error..

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: Failed to find '~/node_modules/shepherd.js/dist/css/shepherd.css'
```

Comment: Usually it's importing from node_modules, so be sure what ~ is alias for node_modules, or even if it really is there.

Comment: Where are you importing your css file containing the ```@import``` statement?

Comment: @Radeanu use I tracked it down.. I'm trying to update the path maybe that'll help

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat well I tried in the component that I'm using shepherd and now I'm trying in my `app.vue` page

Comment: If this doen't help try deleting your node-modules folder and do a ```npm install``` again... just to rule that one out

Comment: arghh.. no luck.. this is crazy.. I'll keep looking, not sure what's going on

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce the error in a Vue CLI generated project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I fixed it using `require()`.

The import will be like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import VueShepherd from 'vue-shepherd';

Vue.use(VueShepherd);

require('shepherd.js/dist/css/shepherd.css');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import 'shepherd.js/dist/css/shepherd.css';
```